# Efficiently count occurrence of an element

Tags: python

thanks for having here.

So I need to create a counter that will calculate how many time a particular Br No. occurred at tank*brand level. And count the occurrence with gap. So this is my actual data and outcome.

dataset:
[image: dataset]

outcome:
[image: outcome]

- Now if we look at Tank 1, the first 3 rows having same tank and same brand and same br so counter = 1, if we look at 6 and 7th row same tank and same brand and same br occurred again with gap in between. so counter will be 2 and again same at last row so that's the counter = 3
- Now if we look at Tank 2, the 4-5th rows having same tank and same brand and same br so counter = 1 but if you see the 2nd last row all same but tank number different, thats counter = 1, if tank no. would have same for above case then we would have wrote 2.

So I want to make this, I have wrote similar code but not working.

```
countr=1
for j in tank_data['Tank No']:
    for i in tank_data.Brand:
    for idx, val in tank_data['Br No']:
        
        if val == tank_data['Br No'].iloc[ix-1]:
            tank_data['instance_counter'] = countr
        elif val != tank_data['Br No'].iloc[ix-1] and val not in tank_data['instance_counter'].unique():
            tank_data['instance_counter'] = countr
        elif val != tank_data['Br No'].iloc[ix-1] and val in tank_data['instance_counter'].unique():
            cout = tank_data[tank_data['Br No']==val]
            cout1 = cout['instance_counter'].max()
            tank_data['instance_counter'] += max
            
    countr = 1   
countr = 1
```

Help Pls?

Answer (score 0):

So, I would do smth like this. I would have the result array, where I will store counters and dictionary of tank*brand level as a key and index in array as value.

```
data = [
    {
        'tank': 'a',
        'brand': 'b'
    },
    {
        'tank': 'a',
        'brand': 'a'
    }
]
result = []
keys = {}

for el in data:
    key = el['tank'] + el['brand']
    if key in keys:
        result[keys[key]] += 1
    else:
        result.append(1)
        keys[key] = len(result - 1)
```